# Create shimmering UIImageView in modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I want to create a shimmering `UIView`, it looks like a facebook placeholder with animation.

I use image for creating placeholder, than I add a gradient layer on top of that with some animation.

```
@IBOutlet weak var shimmeringView: UIImageView!
```

I created an extension of `UIView`, then I call it in `ViewDidLoad`

```
shimmeringView.startShimmering()
```

My code bellow is working in standard view controller, but if I am using it in my view controller that presented modally, it won't work as it is.

```
extension UIView {

    func startShimmering() {
        let light = UIColor.white.cgColor
        let alpha = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [alpha, light, alpha]
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: -self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: 3 * self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.8)
        gradient.locations = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
        self.layer.mask = gradient
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]
        animation.toValue = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
        animation.duration = 1.5
        animation.repeatCount = HUGE
        gradient.add(animation, forKey: "shimmer")
    }

    func stopShimmering(){
        self.layer.mask = nil
    }

}
```

Is there any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Move the startShimmering call to viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear and see if it works. If it does it means that when your view is loaded, the outlet is not initialized yet and it wont work.

Comment: Thanks @gmogames, after delay it for 0.2 sec it works